# An exersise about representation of the fractional parts of an irrational

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, real-numbers, irrational-numbers

> Prove that exists an irrational number $a$ and $\epsilon>0$ such that $\epsilon \leq \{2^na\} \leq 1-\epsilon,\forall n \in \Bbb{N}$.

I have a difficulty solving this.

My first thoughts are to work with binary representation of numbers using the fact that when we multiply a  number in its binary form  with $2^n$ ,we shift its digits $n-$ positions to the left.

And also we thow out some digits because we care about fractional parts.

Can someone help me?

I just want a hint not a full answer.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the irrational expressed in the binary system
$$
\alpha=0.a_1a_2\ldots a_na_{n+1}\ldots, \quad a_i\in\{0,1\}.
$$
Then
$$
2^n\alpha=a_1a_2\ldots a_n.a_{n+1}\ldots
$$
and
$$
\{2^n\alpha\}=0.a_{n+1}a_{n+2}\ldots\,\,\text{or}\,\, 1-0.a_{n+1}a_{n+2}\ldots
$$
You need to find $\varepsilon$ and $a_i$'s such that
$$
\varepsilon<0.a_{n+1}a_{n+2}\ldots, 1-0.a_{n+1}a_{n+2}\ldots<1-\varepsilon
$$
Define $\hat a=1-a$. Then $1-0.a_{n+1}a_{n+2}\ldots=.\hat{a}_{n+1}\hat{a}_{n+2}\ldots$.

Answer. Consider for example, $\varepsilon=1/8$, and a sequence of pairs 
$$
(a_1,a_2), (a_3,a_4),\ldots,(a_{2n-1},a_{2n}),\ldots,
$$
where $a_2=1-a_1$ and this sequence is not periodic.

Comment: Why does this answer the O.P's question? Can you explain a little bit more the final part?